# how can i get access token value from jsonobject of given JSON in Java

Tags: java, json

how can i get access token value from jsonobject of given json  in java?
 This Is my json

`{   "access_token": "1787989djhjhak9cj8",   "token_type": "bber",   "scope": "read write trt" }`

Answer (score 1):

Your json is a string.
1) First convert JSON String to JSONObject 
2) From JSONObject you can ask for access_token

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{   \"access_token\": \"1787989djhjhak9cj8\",   \"token_type\": \"bber\",   \"scope\": \"read write trt\" }");

Object accessToken = jsonObject.get("access_token");
```